# Display selected value from dropdown using semantic ui React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui

I'm really new on React, Redux.
I am trying to display the selected value from dropdown, uses semantic ui.
I updated at state but can not show the value on the screen, and the dropdown not close (after added closeOnChange- not recognize this attribute, why?}

** Component.js**

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
    const {productId} = useParams()
    
    const selectedProd = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products.find(product => 
        product.id === parseInt(productId)
        ));
    const products = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products)       
    let {rank} = selectedProd    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()  
    const handleDropDownSelect = (event) => {
        //update rank
        selectedProd.rank = parseInt(event.dataset.value)       
        //update allProducts
        dispatch(updateProducts(products,selectedProd))        
    }
return(
<div className="ui left floated simple selection dropdown"   value={rank} onClick={e=>handleDropDownSelect(e.target)}>
                                <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
                                <div className="default value" value={rank}></div>
                                <div className="left floated menu" >
                                <div className="item" data-value="1" data-key="1">1</div>
                                <div className="item" data-value="2" data-key="2">2</div>
                                <div className="item" data-value="3" data-key="3">3</div>
                                <div className="item" data-value="4" data-key="4">4</div>
                                <div className="item" data-value="5" data-key="5">5</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>)
```

**redux/reducers/actions.js**

```
export const updateProducts = (products,product) => {
    const indexOfItem = products.findIndex(q => q.id === product.id);
    if (indexOfItem > -1) {
        products[indexOfItem] = product;
     }
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.SET_PRODUCTS,
        payload: products
    };
};
```

**redux/constans/types.js**

```
export const ActionTypes = {
    SET_PRODUCTS: "SET_PRODUCTS",   
}
```

**redux/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { productReducer} from './productReducer'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    allProducts: productReducer,    
})

export default reducers
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely you do NOT change the reference of  `state.allProducts.products`, so React doesn't re-render the UI

You should `map` products as the [Redux Todos Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos?file=/src/reducers/todos.js)

And add a online demo such as [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/) would help us give you better suggestions

OK, according to the demo at [codesandbox.io/s/products-forked-kmbwz](https://codesandbox.io/s/products-forked-kmbwz), here we have at leaset two problems:

1. the Route `ProductDetails` didn't rerender after the dropdown select chance because of you didn't change the reference of `selectedProd`.

View on [this link I forked from yours](https://codesandbox.io/s/products-forked-lp1e3?file=/src/Components/ProductDetails.js), see file `/src/Components/ProductDetails.js` on Line 14-15,  I add a console.log to debug the Component whether will be rerendered. And Line 31-33, I change the reference of new `selectedProd` by  destructuring assignment. The when you click the dropdown option, the UI will be rerender, because you see the log.

2. The dropdown component is buggy:

- You bind a value to `div`. But `div` doesn't have a `value` prop, you should explicitly display it as I do at Line 54.
- click the value part of dropdown will trigger `handleDropDownSelect` event, so you will see NaN sometimes

I really suggest you follow the [official Redux Todos Example](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react) before you start. And the problem you face here is that, React naturally render the UI when data(props/state) change, so the reference of data is change or not is important to React. And as you play React longer, immutable data structure such as [Immerjs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) will help a lot. And again, the Redux or React docs are much more detailed than I explained, read them

Comment: its changed  the reference of  state.allProducts.products

Comment: the demo is broken

Comment: emptied the entire folder of redux :( . fixed

Answer (score 0):

We would like to help you, but there is too little code (especially missing redux part and how you're passing values/functions to react components). Please link your repository / show us more code.